# Why there is need of creating a reference of child class?

Tags: c#

Suppose that I have two classes, parentclass and childclass, and childclass inherits the parent class

```
class childclass : parentclass
{
  childclass c = new childclass();             //instance 
  parentclass p = c ;//  reference of parentclass
  childclass c1= (childclass )p;// reference of childclass
}
```

My question is, what is the use of reference to childclass while we can access the data using the instance of the chlidclass?

Comment: The code you show looks pretty strange indeed. But what is the actual case where it is used?

Comment: Here we go again with the downvotes. Why don't you, instead of downvoting, try to help answering the question, formatting the code, or guide the OP in the right direction? SMH SO.

Comment: @Hanlet Downvotes mean, as the tooltip says, "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Pretty sure this meets *all* of those criteria.

Comment: @CodyGray I understand, and I know the question does in fact meet all of those criteria, but just blindly downvoting a question and not guiding - even a little bit - the newer users is what makes me feel a little bit like sometime we aren't helping as much as we could.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I agree, especially on the newer users, I do think that we should be more lenient

Comment: I think , i was expecting answer

Comment: The code in "childclass" will be used when you create an object of "childclass" - The code you have presented seems to create a loop and does not make much sense (unless you have an example in mind) to do what you are doing. Not every arrangement of code is meaningful. Some, may be harmful! You may want to check 'static' class types that have 1 single instance and does not require a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no common use case that I can think of. Even assuming that this is just a minimal example (since you'd obviously *never* do this in three lines of code, one right after the other), if you find yourself writing this, it is a good sign that you are [not taking proper advantage of polymorphism](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245263/how-to-avoid-downcasting).

In order for a downcast like this one to succeed, you have to *know* that the object is actually an instance of the more derived class. How do you know that? More specifically, how do you keep track of this bookkeeping information in the design of your program?

You have to either carry around tags with the objects telling you what their actual type is, which is completely subverting the point of polymorphic design, or you have to *attempt* a series of downcasts and check for success/failure, which is tedious, error-prone, fragile, and also missing the point.

Admittedly, there are probably cases where this is absolutely necessary. Most of the examples I can think of predated the introduction of support for generics in the C# language.

For instance, the WinForms event-handling model. Each time an event is raised, it passes a reference to an `Object` base class to the event-handling delegate. If the delegate *knows* that the Object reference is *actually* a particular derived class type, it can downcast it and use it as that type (for example, if you're handling a `Button.Click` event, you can probably safely assume that the sending object is of type `Button`).

But like I said, there are better ways of doing this that take better advantage of polymorphism design, and especially now with the introduction of generics.

As for why the language supports it, that's a completely different question, and probably one that can't get a good answer except from the language designers themselves. There certainly are object-oriented languages that prevent downcasting altogether. However, that's a pretty restrictive philosophy, and design often involves compromise. C# allows that compromise to be made.

Answer (score 0):

Below code explains the use of it:

```
class Parent
{
  public void foo(){ Console.WriteLine("Parent foo"); }
  public virtual void foo1() {Console.WriteLine("Parent foo1");}
}

class Child : Parent // class Child extends Parent
{
  public void foo() { Console.WriteLine("Child foo"); }
  public override void foo1(){ Console.WriteLine("Child foo1"); }
}

  public static void Main()
  {
     Child child = new Child();
     Parent parent = new Parent();
     parent = child;// is perfectly valid.
     //child = parent;// is not valid. Error

     parent.foo();
     parent.foo1();
  }
```

Output will be:
Parent foo
Child foo1

Comment: I think that the case above does not exactly match the original example in the question.